# How to pass JavaFX variable into CSS style?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-css

I want to take selected color and change background color of button.

```
private void  handleItemBackAction(ActionEvent eve)
{
          System.out.println("You clicked Set Background Color of Item!");     

        java.awt.Color color=JColorChooser.showDialog(null,"Select a color",java.awt.Color.CYAN);

        String hex = Integer.toHexString(color.getRGB() & 0xffffff);

        hex="#"+hex;
        Text.setText(hex);
        ShortcutButton.setStyle("-fx-background-color: hex;");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put variable content value instead of its name:

```
ShortcutButton.setStyle("-fx-background-color: " + hex + ";");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the color you want in your hex variable.

```
if (!buttonColor.getStyle().trim().contains("-fx-background-color:" +hex)){   
    buttonColor.setStyle("-fx-background-color: " + hex + ";");
}
```

Comment: What if there is a style "-fx-**border**-color: hex;"?

Comment: you're right - either check for the whole property or skip this check altogether.